# Issue with install DSC extension on Azure VM during deployment using Terraform

Tags: azure, dsc, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to use the information in this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-template#default-configuration-script

to onboard a VM to Azure Automation at deployment time and apply a configuration.

I am using Terraform to do the deployment, below is the code I am using for the extensions:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "cse-dscconfig" {
  name                    = "${var.vm_name}-dscconfig-cse"
  location                = "${azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.location}"
  resource_group_name     = "${azurerm_resource_group.my_rg.name}"
  virtual_machine_name    = "${azurerm_virtual_machine.my_vm.name}"
  publisher               = "Microsoft.Powershell"
  type                    = "DSC"
  type_handler_version    = "2.76"
  depends_on              = ["azurerm_virtual_machine.my_vm"]

  settings = <<SETTINGS
        {
          "configurationArguments": {
              "RegistrationUrl": "${var.endpoint}",
              "NodeConfigurationName": "VMConfig"
          }
        }
        SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
        {
                "configurationArguments": {
                  "registrationKey": {
                    "userName": "NOT_USED",
                    "Password": "${var.key}"
                  }
                }
        }
        PROTECTED_SETTINGS
}
```

I am getting the `RegistrationURL` value at execution time by running the command below and passing the value into Terraform:

```
$endpoint = (Get-AzureRmAutomationRegistrationInfo -ResourceGroupName $tf_state_rg -AutomationAccountName $autoAcctName).Endpoint
```

I am getting the `Password` value at execution time by running the command below and passing the value into Terraform:

```
$key = (Get-AzureRmAutomationRegistrationInfo -ResourceGroupName $tf_state_rg -AutomationAccountName $autoAcctName).PrimaryKey
```

I can tell from the logs on the VM that the extension is getting installed but never registers with the Automation Account.

Comment: i think you are supposed to give it configuration package url?

Comment: @4c74356b41 The documentation says: "Specifies the URL of the Automation endpoint where the node attempts to register."

Comment: yeah, probably. i've never see this `default configuration script`. it was not a thing when I was using dsc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was. The documentation is thin on details in some areas so it really was by trial and error that I discovered what was causing the problem. I had the wrong value in the `NodeConfigurationName` properties. What the documentation says about this property: `Specifies the node configuration in the Automation account to assign to the node.` Not having much experience with DSC, I interrupted this to mean the name of the configuration as seen in the `Configurations` section of the `State configuration (DSC)` blade of the Automation Account in the Azure portal.

What the `NodeConfigurationName` property is really referring to is the `Node` definition inside the configuration and it should be in the format of ConfigurationName.NodeName. As an example, the name of my configuration is `VMConfig` and in the config source I have a `Node` block defined called `localhost`. So, with this...the value of the `NodeConfigurationName` property should be `VMConfig.localhost`.